# Linker error when trying to implement encapsulation in C

Tags: c, linker-errors

Consider these files:

obj.h

```
#pragma once
struct obj;

int obj_size(void);
void obj_set_id(struct obj*, int);
int get_obj_id(struct obj*);
```

obj.c

```
#include "obj.h"


struct obj
{
    int id;
};

int obj_size(void) {
    return sizeof(struct obj);
}

void obj_setid(struct obj* o, int i) {
    o->id = i;
}

int obj_getid(struct obj* o) {
    return o->id;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "obj.c"

int main()
{
    puts("hello world");
}
```

As it turns out, this is the way to implement encapsulation in C (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer#C). However when I try to compile that I get a linker error. These are Visual Studio's complaints:

> Error LNK2005 _obj_getid already defined in obj.obj
>   Error LNK2005 _obj_setid already defined in obj.obj
>   Error LNK2005 _obj_size already defined in obj.obj
>   Error LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found

It's set to compile as C code if anyone's wondering.

These are the errors I get when I try to compile it with clang:

```
 clang-7 -pthread -lm -o main main.c obj.c
/tmp/obj-36b460.o: In function `obj_getid':
obj.c:(.text+0x30): multiple definition of `obj_getid'
/tmp/main-a2c3dc.o:main.c:(.text+0x30): first defined here
/tmp/obj-36b460.o: In function `obj_setid':
obj.c:(.text+0x10): multiple definition of `obj_setid'
/tmp/main-a2c3dc.o:main.c:(.text+0x10): first defined here
/tmp/obj-36b460.o: In function `obj_size':
obj.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `obj_size'
/tmp/main-a2c3dc.o:main.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/main-a2c3dc.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `obj_set_id'
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
compiler exit status 1
```

I've tried `extern`-ing the function declarations in `obj.h`, but that didn't work either. Same thing for `inline`-ing them.

Comment: Include `obj.h` in `main.c`, not `obj.c`.

Comment: Never include .c files.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError It's compiling now, but I can't even instantiate `struct obj`.

Comment: Post another question.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Do I do it like this: `void* obj = malloc(sizeof(obj_size()));
 obj_setid(obj, 5);
 printf("%d\n", obj_getid(obj));
 free(obj);`

Comment: @SergeyTeryan You can find the rationale for the rate limit here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256323/questions-are-now-rate-limited-to-1-per-90-minutes

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I've been told to ask another one, so that rationale is apparently irrelevant to my case.

Comment: @SergeyTeryan Sorry for the misunderstanding. You can find a more thorough explanation here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answering your question in its current state:*

Your error is to include "obj.c" instead of "obj.h".

The `#include` directive works (shortly said) such as if the contents of the named file replaces the directive.

If you compile "main.c" and "obj.c" you are giving everything in "obj.c" twice to the linker. That's why it gives you the error.

---

You can edit your question to update it if you have new information.